# How do I get more than 1000 matching results through sphinx search?

Tags: php, sphinx

How do I get more than 1000 matching results through sphinx search?

Comment: Finally I got it thanks:- 

Refer this links:- http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/api-func-setlimits.html

Change the max_matches setting in your sphinx.yml file

This is felix , it will working fine . 
1) indexer with max_matches 
2) searchd with ...
3) Refer " set limit (....)" functions will use full for you

Answer (score 1):

Change the `max_matches` setting in your sphinx.yml file

Comment: Thanks Robert, but I already Changed the "max_matches" but i got an 1000 matching Results only , ...

Comment: That would have been nice to know up front.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that might still be helpful (sphinxsearch forum).

```
select * from mytable where id > 10 limit 2000 option max_matches=2000
```